# Code only works if I alert out before the code that's bombing out?

Tags: javascript

This is just freakin weird to me.  So if I don't

```
    function BindAlbumAndPhotoData()
    {
        // Get an array of all the user's Albums
        var aAlbums = GetAllAlbums(userID, token);

        alert("aAlbums: " + aAlbums);
        if (aAlbums == null || aAlbums == "undefined")
            return;

        // Set the default albumID
        var defaultAlbumID = aAlbums[0].id;

    };
```

So I get an undefined error on the line var defaultAlbumID = aAlbums[0].id; if I don't uncomment the alert("aAlbums: " + aAlbums);

what the heck?  If I comment out alert("aAlbums: " + aAlbums); then I get an undefined for the var defaultAlbumID = aAlbums[0].id;

This is so weird.  I've been working all night to figure out why I kept getting an undefined for the aAlbum[0] and as soon as I add back an alert that I used to have above it, all is fine...makes no sense to me.

Here's the full code of GetAllAlbums:

```
function GetAllAlbums(userID, accessToken)
{
    var aAlbums = []; // array
    var uri = "/" + userID + "/albums?access_token=" + accessToken;

    alert("uri: " + uri);

    FB.api(uri, function (response) 
    {
        // check for a valid response
        if (!response || response.error) 
        {
            alert("error occured");
            return;
        }

        for (var i = 0, l = response.data.length; i < l; i++) 
        {
            alert("Album #: " + i + "\r\n" +
                  "response.data[i].id: " + response.data[i].id + "\r\n" +
                  "response.data[i].name: " + response.data[i].name + "\r\n" +
                  "response.data[i].count: " + response.data[i].count + "\r\n" +
                  "response.data[i].link: " + response.data[i].link
                  );

            aAlbums[i] = new Album(
                                                    response.data[i].id,
                                                    response.data[i].name,
                                                    response.data[i].count,
                                                    response.data[i].link
                                                   );

            alert("aAlbums[" + i + "].id : " + aAlbums[i].id);
        }
    });

    return aAlbums;
}
```

so I'm not returning the array until I hit the callback of the FB.api async call so I don't see how my defaultAlbumID = aAlbums[0].id; line of code is executing before I have a valid array of data back.  When I put in the alert, ovbvioulsly it's delaying before it hits my line defaultAlbumID = aAlbums[0].id; causing it to I guess luckily have data beacuse the async FB.api call is done but again I don't see how that's even possible to have an issue like this when I'm waiting for the call before proceeding on and returning the array to aAlbums in my BindAlbumAndPhotoData() method.

**UPDATE #3**

```
            function BindAlbumAndPhotoData()
            {
                GetAllAlbums(userID, accessToken, function (aAlbums) 
                {
                    alert("we're back and should have data");

                    if (aAlbums === null || aAlbums === undefined) {
                        alert("array is empty");
                        return false;
                    }

                    var defaultAlbumID = aAlbums[0].id;

                    // Set the default albumID
                    var defaultAlbumID = aAlbums[0].id;

                    // Bind the album dropdown
                    alert(" defaultAlbumID: " + defaultAlbumID);

                 });
            };


function GetAllAlbums(userID, accessToken, callbackFunctionSuccess)
{
    var aAlbums = []; // array
    var uri = "/" + userID + "/albums?access_token=" + accessToken;

    FB.api(uri, function (response) 
    {
        // check for a valid response
        if (!response || response.error) 
        {
            alert("error occured");
            return;
        }

        for (var i = 0, l = response.data.length; i < l; i++) 
        {
            alert("Album #: " + i + "\r\n" +
                  "response.data[i].id: " + response.data[i].id + "\r\n" +
                  "response.data[i].name: " + response.data[i].name + "\r\n" +
                  "response.data[i].count: " + response.data[i].count + "\r\n" +
                  "response.data[i].link: " + response.data[i].link
                  );

            aAlbums[i] = new Album(
                                                    response.data[i].id,
                                                    response.data[i].name,
                                                    response.data[i].count,
                                                    response.data[i].link
                                                   );

            alert("aAlbums[" + i + "].id : " + aAlbums[i].id);
        }

        // pass the array back to the callback function sent as a param to the GetAllAlbums method here
        callbackFunctionSuccess(aAlbums); 
    });
}
```

It's not hitting my alert in the callback.  I must still be doing something wrong here.

**UPDATE #4** - for some reason it's not hitting my FB.api callback now.

```
function GetAllAlbums(userID, accessToken, callbackFunctionSuccess)
{
    var aAlbums = []; // array
    var uri = "/" + userID + "/albums?access_token=" + accessToken;

    alert("uri: " + uri);

    FB.api(uri, function (response) 
    {
        // check for a valid response
        if (!response || response.error) 
        {
            alert("error occured");
            return;
        }

        for (var i = 0, l = response.data.length; i < l; i++) {
            alert("Album #: " + i + "\r\n" +
                  "response.data[i].id: " + response.data[i].id + "\r\n" +
                  "response.data[i].name: " + response.data[i].name + "\r\n" +
                  "response.data[i].count: " + response.data[i].count + "\r\n" +
                  "response.data[i].link: " + response.data[i].link
                  );

            aAlbums[i] = new Album(
                                                    response.data[i].id,
                                                    response.data[i].name,
                                                    response.data[i].count,
                                                    response.data[i].link
                                                   );

            alert("aAlbums[" + i + "].id : " + aAlbums[i].id);
        }

        alert("about to pass back the array to the callback function");
        // pass the array back to the callback function sent as a param to the GetAllAlbums method here
        callbackFunctionSuccess(aAlbums);
    });
}
```

Comment: you're maybe doing ajax here (`GetAllAlbums(userID, token);`), are you not?

Comment: what does `GetAllAlbums(userID, token);` do?

Comment: yes...but I still don't get it.

Comment: GetAllAlbums makes a JS SDK ajax call to go get the albums and returns an array of custom album objects

Comment: so then it's hitting my var defaultAlbumID = aAlbums[0].id;
 before the async call is done?

Comment: Yeah, this is a classic sign that your script is trying to do stuff with something that hasn't (completely) loaded yet.

Comment: ok so not sure how to handle this.

Comment: I do wait for the async callback though so don't know what the issue is here.  See update above in the original thread

Comment: See above, the update to the thread.  I don't even see how it's even getting to my var defaultAlbumID = aAlbums[0].id; because in my GetAllAlbums, I'm waiting for the response in the callback of FB.api so how would it ven get to var defaultAlbumID = aAlbums[0].id; until that's done getting the data in the response?

Comment: You don't need the 'return' on the last line - just execute the function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function BindAlbumAndPhotoData()
{
    // Get an array of all the user's Albums
    GetAllAlbums(userID, token, function(aAlbums){

        // Set the default albumID
        var defaultAlbumID = aAlbums[0].id;

    });

};
```

and then in the GetAllAlbums function call the success function when you have the data back

//********* AFTER THE BREAK *******//

In response to the updated question: The FB API is mostly asynchronous, and will keep executing other code while it waits.  So using your code, all I have done is passed in the function, and then call the function you've passed it at the end

```
function GetAllAlbums(userID, accessToken, funcSuccess)
{
    var aAlbums = []; // array
    var uri = "/" + userID + "/albums?access_token=" + accessToken;

alert("uri: " + uri);

FB.api(uri, function (response) 
{
    // check for a valid response
    if (!response || response.error) 
    {
        alert("error occured");
        return;
    }

    for (var i = 0, l = response.data.length; i < l; i++) 
    {
        alert("Album #: " + i + "\r\n" +
              "response.data[i].id: " + response.data[i].id + "\r\n" +
              "response.data[i].name: " + response.data[i].name + "\r\n" +
              "response.data[i].count: " + response.data[i].count + "\r\n" +
              "response.data[i].link: " + response.data[i].link
              );

        aAlbums[i] = new Album(
                                                response.data[i].id,
                                                response.data[i].name,
                                                response.data[i].count,
                                                response.data[i].link
                                               );

        alert("aAlbums[" + i + "].id : " + aAlbums[i].id);



    }

    funcSuccess(aAlbums);
});
```

}

Comment: I'm using the Facebook SDK to make JS ajax calls.

Comment: Then instead of the jquery bit in the function there, from the FB examples i've seen you'd want something like ajax.ondone = function(data) { funcSuccess(data); };

The only reason I wrap it inside another function is that it leaves you the room to do some quality control (if data!=null) etc

Comment: jamie, thanks.  Check out my update above to the thread...see my function there for GetAllAlbums.

Comment: so now that I've showed you how my GetAllAlbums() is working, I don't now if your example makes sense using GetAllAlbums(userID, token, function(aAlbums){... because I'm using the callback of FB.api to wait for the response.  I don't understand your syntax I guess either with the funcSuccess anyway in how you added it as a param there.

Comment: but what is url: "thisurl", for when the FB.api is sending the request, not a jQuery ajax function?

Comment: "So using your code, all I have done is passed in the function"  what function do you mean by the function...I'm lost.  So you passed in what to the GetAllAlbums?

Comment: so basically you added a callback to GetAllAlbums which will be called once the funcSuccess(aAlbums); is returned?  I guess I don't get callbacks in terms of how they talk to each other here.

Comment: so function (aAlbums) in BindAlbumAndPhotoData()
 is called by funcSuccess(aAlbums); at the end of my GetAllAlbums and sends back the array...I think I got it.  I don't even think I need the jQuery.  The FB.api sits and waits for the data in its own callback via the response object.

Comment: Sorry, I removed the jquery reference, it was a double up and completely unnecessary. And yup your last comment was completely right :) - I find this method of callbacks really handy, as it means your ajax calls can be more generic

Comment: ok I tried this, I think I get it...see update.  I'm not getting the alert to fire though on the callback.

Comment: Just commented on the original post, don't 'return' the function, just execute it :)

Comment: yea, just saw that.  But still not hitting my callback for some reason..let me do some more testing.  For some reson now it's not hitting the callback for FB.api(uri, function (response) { });

Comment: That is strange, well if you don't get somewhere soon post your code somewhere online so I can have a play

Comment: awesome it's working THANK YOU SO MUCH.  I just learned truly how callbacks work, not just relying on some third party API.  It's really essential to know how to do this with plain JS.

Answer (score 1):

Try three equals signs instead of two, and also... return false rather than nothing at all.

```
if (aAlbums === null || aAlbums === undefined)
            return false;
```

Also, undefined doesn't need to be in quotes, otherwise, it's just considered a string with a value of "undefined"

On an added note, it's probably better to ALSO check if aAlbums is actually an array before you decide to return a key from it.

```
if (   aAlbums === null 
    || aAlbums === undefined
    || (typeof(aAlbums)=='object'&& !(aAlbums instanceof Array))
    } return false;
```

Comment: As you put it, it's `undefined` not `"undefined"`

Comment: this did not make a difference:            if (   aAlbums === null 
                || aAlbums === undefined
                || (typeof(aAlbums)=='object'&& !(aAlbums instanceof Array))
                ) return false;

Comment: please see my update to the main thread..added the GetAllAlbums function to show you how that works.

Answer (score 1):

Is your function `GetAllAlbums()` doing some HTTP requests? If so then you need to either make that call synchronous or you need to put your code into a function and pass that as a callback to the Ajax request.

Comment: yes doing that already in the callback of FB.api.  See my updated post.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your condition like this:

```
  if (typeof aAlbums == 'undefined')
      return;
```

Also make sure that `aAlbums` has values and is an array:

```
alert(aAlbums.length);
```

Or:

```
for(var i = 0; i < aAlbums.length; i++)
{
  alert(aAlbums[i].id);
}
```

Comment: well I get a length of zero even though I know the array has values in it...weird.

Comment: if (typeof aAlbums == 'undefined')
                    return; doesn't work or make any difference..just tested.

Comment: @coffeeaddict: If its length is 0 then it is not filled with data, not an array. Make sure that function `GetAllAlbums` works fine.

Comment: it will return zero because you are waiting for the `ajax` data when that script line get executed... too slow for the computer, too fast for your eye... that's why you are seeing the data but JS says it's undefined...

Comment: getalbums is working only if I put that alert in there meaning it gives it a chance to run before it hits var defaultAlbumID = aAlbums[0].id; I think....

Comment: please see my update to the main thread..added the GetAllAlbums function to show you how that works.

Comment: No, I'm saying not to use quotes because undefined is a reserved property in Javascript already.  If you were to use quotes, then you're assuming that in your GetAllAlbums function, you actually assigned the string "undefined" to it's return; which you didn't.

The triple equals sign is just a stricter comparison.